# C# Query: 'System.InvalidOperationException' | Additional information: Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql

```
connectionString = @"server=localhost;database=" + lbDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";userid=root;password=;";

        string query = "SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE id = 1";

        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Hello,

I have this problem when I run the following code. I get this not so very specific error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Connection must be valid and open.

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it,

Thank you.

Comment: Well the exception seems pretty clear. You don't have a valid, open connection. Look at your code - where do you think you're opening the connection? Try `connect.Open()`...

Comment: The connection is already opened by another methode. When I add connect.Open() it says the connection is already open.

Comment: Then there's code you haven't shown us, which makes it hard to help you...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gHaHqxcr

Comment: No, please edit this question - it should be standalone.

Comment: I up voted just because, after programming for 12 hours straight, I also left out the Open statement ... then spent 10 minutes wondering what was wrong. Sometimes the obvious mistakes are the ones we don't see. Thank goodness for SO! :D

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for MySql Connectionstring is as follows:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Note that you are using 'userid' and 'password' instead of 'uid' and 'pwd'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Connection String is Right .. Try This

```
connectionString = @"server=localhost;database=" + lbDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";userid=root;password=;";

    string query = "SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE id = 1";

    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);


    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);

    connect.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 /*Do Whatever You Want To Do Here */

connect.Close();
```

You Can Refer this Link for Reference.
[Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Trying to validate a login information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546570/exception-system-invalidoperationexception-trying-to-validate-a-login-informati)

Hope  This Helps :)